# Debugger breaks when IE is default browser, but not when Chrome is default browser

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a web app I am building in VS2010.  There are errors in the scripts that run on some of the pages.  I hit F5 to debug the app.  When using IE as my default browser, the debugger breaks at these errors in the javascripts; When using Chrome as my default browser, the debugger does not break;  How do I get the debugger to break on script errors when Chrome is my default browser?  EDIT: A further thing I've noticed is that when debugging in IE, if I stop debugging, then IE exits.  Vice versa, if I close ID, then the debugger stops.  However, this same "link" does not seem to exist between the debugger and Chrome.  If I stop Chrome, the visual studio debugger is still running, and if I stop the debugger in visual studio, Chrome is still running with the site that I was debugging.  Do I just live with the fact that when debugging using Chrome, the debugger will not break on javascript errors, because there is no real "link" between the VS debugger and Chrome?

Comment: Searching the internets for this exact issue. Any news? Thanks.

Comment: I have noticed the same issue and I am also looking for a solution.

Comment: Nope...still no solution...I've learned to switch my default browser to IE when doing debugging.  Then back to Chrome when I'm not in "work mode".